# UNIX: redirect some commands with pipe

Tags: shell, unix, command

I'm new with Unix.  The following is the command I'm executing.

```
$ time ls | wget exampledomain.com > output.txt
```

I would like the command to output the time it took to retrieve the information to the output.txt. This command I have creates the output.txt but it's just a blank document.

Thank you

Comment: What's the point of piping `ls` to `wget`?

Comment: Good point Arkadiusz. In the long run I would like to just extract the time it took to retrieve the information and output it into a text file. I thought time ls would make that easier since it has less extraneous information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wget` outputs to stderr. Use:

```
wget exampledomain.com > out 2>&1
# or
wget exampledomain.com 2>out
# or 
wget exampledomain.com --output-file=log
# or, to redirect the output both to file and stdout
wget exampledomain.com 2>&1 | tee log
```